# Does Vachaspati Mishra's depiction of Vishnu's marriage have a scriptural basis?

Tags: vishnu, bhagavata-purana, shloka, lakshmi

The Vivada Chintamani is a work by the Advaita philosopher Vachaspati Mishra on the teachings of Dharma Shastras concerning law.  Vachaspati Mishra [begins](https://ia600203.us.archive.org/BookReader/BookReaderImages.php?zip=/26/items/vivadachintaman00vcgoog/vivadachintaman00vcgoog_jp2.zip&file=vivadachintaman00vcgoog_jp2/vivadachintaman00vcgoog_0117.jp2&scale=16&rotate=0) the Vivada Chintamani with an invocation to Vishnu:

> That goddess, who is the genetrix of the universe, emerging from the sea of milk, looks askance at the assembly of gods, perceives by the glances of one of them that he would wed her, and bends down her head through bashfulness.  The god, moved by love, which gave rise to the desire of embracing, holds the goddess with his perspiring hand, whereon she smiles.  May that god vouchsafe protection from destruction. Having prostrated before Narayana ... the author, Vachaspati Mishra, compiles the work Vivada Chintamani.

Now clearly this is a reference to Vishnu's marriage to Lakshmi after the Churning of the Ocean.  (Or to be more technical, Vyuha Vasudeva's marriage, as opposed to Para Vasudeva who is eternally married to Sridevi.)  This story is described in many scriptures including [this chapter](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/8/8/chapter-view) of the Srimad Bhagavatam.

But my question is, does the specific description of Vishnu and Lakshmi given by Vachaspati Mishra have a basis in Hindu scripture?  I'm talking about details like Lakshmi bending down her head in shyness, Vishnu's hand sweating, Lakshmi smiling, etc.  Or is this just poetic license on Vachaspati Mishra's part?

It's perfectly possible that these details are true, as it could be one of the Lilas of Sriman Narayana.

Comment: Yes. I remember reading the same description in a Purana. Let me check.

Comment: Just noticed, this is 6000th question on this site. Cool though :p